# c# Splitting a pdf file with PdfSplitter in itext7 will double the file size?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, itext7

Splitting pdf files with PdfSplitter in itext7 will cause the file size to double, split into several files will multiply several times, is there any way to avoid it. If you merge these files again, you get a file that is n times the size.
[TestFile](https://1drv.ms/b/s!AqxJcIfHZ18Uklja_oD_CiXvsOZz?e=fXUBbw)

```
private sealed class _PdfSplitter_95 : PdfSplitter
{
    public _PdfSplitter_95(PdfDocument baseArg1, string pdfPath)
        : base(baseArg1)
    {
        this._pdfPath = pdfPath;
    }

    string _pdfPath;
    int currPageIndex = 0;
    protected override PdfWriter GetNextPdfWriter(PageRange documentPageRange)
    {
        currPageIndex++;
        return new PdfWriter(_pdfPath.Replace(".pdf", $"_{currPageIndex}.pdf"));
    }
}


static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string inputFileName = @"TestSplit.pdf";
    using (PdfDocument inputPdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(inputFileName)))
    {
        _PdfSplitter_95 _PdfSplitter_95 = new _PdfSplitter_95(inputPdfDoc, inputFileName);

        IList<PdfDocument> splitDocuments = _PdfSplitter_95.SplitByPageCount(1);
        foreach (PdfDocument doc in splitDocuments)
        {
            doc.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In a PDF the pages may share resources (fonts, images,...). When you split the file into multiple PDFs, those shared resources have to be copied into each partial pdf that uses them. This can make the summed up sizes explode. Whether this causes the issue in your case or whether it's something else, cannot be said without more details like code and example PDFs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a PDF splitter to export pages as lean files there must be few common overheads so by removing all the bloat in a non readable PDF file (so it is optimised as smaller) we can then export pages as between 2 KB up to a significantly smaller maximum here 2 pages of dense text are a max 750 KB from the 4.7 MB source data.
[image]

Those two pages could be much smaller themselves if using fonts rather than shapes.

[image]

As readable text with an imbedded font it could be say 83 KB (3 KB of text and 80 KB of 2 supporting fonts) rather than 764 KB as scalable vectors.

[image]

So What is the Answer to your page splitting problem ? And you may not like it, but it requires a human to **re-export from the source as readable text** not an illustraton wrapped in a PDF outer, with more MetaData than each page warrants. Inkscape (untested) may be an alternative exporter from source?

A viable alternative is to use a "Print With OCR" approach before splitting the pages out, as that generates a much smaller start file (at the cost of image quality) but a readable fontless file Here we see an iceni based GUI did a very good job. File is under 14 MB with 16 backgrounds and could be smaller without the 3 blank images.

[image]